# How To Set Up second Apache Virtual Hosts on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, virtualhost

I have one virtual host but when i make second one and going to check ping its goes to first one website, and when check in browser its says 404 not found, but first one works fine.

Comment: Please, share configuration for both virtualhosts

Comment: in /var/www/html/ there are two virtual host example.com and example1.com then /public_html then my folder. and in /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf

Comment: and in /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public_html
        serverAlias www.example.com
   Alias /phpmyadmin "/usr/share/phpmyadmin/"
<Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin/">
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

Comment: and second one /etc/apache2/sites-available/example1.com.conf <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example1.com/public_html
        serverAlias www.example1.com
   Alias /phpmyadmin "/usr/share/phpmyadmin/"
<Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin/">
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

Comment: It's not a good idea to use more then 1 DEFAULT virtual host: VirtualHost *:80

Comment: Ok so please suggest me what write on second one ?

Comment: I've posted an answer for your question

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the [edit] button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1 Setup correct records for domain names in** `/etc/hosts`.

This means that you are running `apache2` on same computer that you are trying to get access to it via browser. Otherwise, set correct IP address.

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
127.0.0.1 example1.com
```

**2 Adjust your apache virtualhost configuration**

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf`

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html

    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/example.com/public_html/ >
            Require all granted
            AllowOverride All
            Options Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/example1.com.conf`

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example1.com
    ServerName example1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example1.com/public_html

    ErrorLog /var/www/example1.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example1.com/logs/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/example1.com/public_html/ >
            Require all granted
            AllowOverride All
            Options Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**3 Create required directories**

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/example.com/{public_html,logs}
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/example1.com/{public_html,logs}
```

**4 Enable virtualhosts**

```
sudo a2ensite example.com
sudo a2ensite example1.com
```

**5 Restart apache2 for apply changes**

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

**6 Check that it works**

Create different index files for both hosts

```
echo "example.com" | sudo tee /var/www/example.com/public_html/index.html
echo "example1.com" | sudo tee /var/www/example1.com/public_html/index.html
```

Open browser and navigate to `example.com`. You should see "example.com"

Navigate to `example1.com`. You should see "example1.com".

Comment: Got one Apache error" Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server"

Comment: check out your `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`, it should contain `Listen 80` or `Listen 127.0.0.1:80` directive.
Additionally, provide last records from /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: Also, be sure that you have created all required directories. If apache can't create log file - it can't start

Comment: when second one works fine then first one cant access those file or folder, now example1.com works fine but example.com file/folder cant access in browser its goes to not found.

Comment: oh! do you need 2 virtual hosts with 1 document root?

Comment: if you need to get access to 1 file from different locations, you should create symlink for this file and add `FollowSymLinks` option to directory definition in your apache config

Comment: no i need two virtual hosts in two documents root so like if i open example.com then i need different folder and if i open example1.com then i need different folder, "FollowSymLinks" cant understand how i use it ?